# Is this problem a particular case of some known theorem of Real Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f \in C[0,2]$ is such that $f(0)=f(2)$ then there exist $x_1$ and $x_2 \in [0,2]$ such that $x_1 -x_2=1$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

The solution of this problem is easy one can just take the function $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ and Using Intermediate value theorem gives the result.

But I'm Interested in general statement of this kind of problem,I'm pretty sure that this problem is a particular case of some theorem which I once saw on MSE but now I'm unable to recall.Can someone please help me?

Comment: Substitute $[a,b]=[0,2]$ and $1=(b-a)/2$ for a more general statement of this theorem.

Comment: @Crostul Thats true but I guess something more general is true.Something about $x_1-x_2$ can be any integer (With some conditions of course) ?

Comment: I think it's typically stated with $2\pi$ instead of 2. It's not a more general question but it might help.